# ASP.NET Core 3.1: Add framework service: IHostEnvironment

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core 3.1 application and I'm trying to inject the framework service IHostEnvironment in my ConfigureServices so I can get the environment in my application service and the application is throwing an error.

Startup.cs:

```
private IHostEnvironment _env;
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
{
Configuration = configuration;
_env = hostEnvironment;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
//add framework services
services.AddSingleton<IHostEnvironment>(_env);

//add application services
services.AddSingleton<IMySvc, MySvc>();

}
```

MySvc.cs

```
public class MySvc : IMySvc
{
private IConfigurationRoot _config;
//private IHostingEnvironment _env;
private IHostEnvironment _env;

public string Env{
get{
if(_env.IsDevelopment()){return _config["MyConfiguration: MyProperty"];}
}
}
public HttpSvc(IConfigurationRoot config, IHostEnvironment env)
{
_config = config;
_env = env;
}

}
```

The application fails to run complaining about some services not being able to be constructed.

Comment: Can you please share exact error?

Comment: But I would guess that `HttpSvc(IConfigurationRoot config` can be changed to `HttpSvc(IConfiguration config`

Comment: From ASP.NET Core 3.1 onwards, it's IWebHostEnvironment. Just found this out.

Comment: Yes, this was the change also.

Comment: @GuruStron: If you post your comment as the answer, I'll accept it. I changed IHostEnvironment to IWebHostEnvironment and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the migration guide from 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#startup-changes) `IWebHostEnvironment` should be injected in the `Startup` class instead of `IHostingEnvironment`. Also I would suggest to consider injecting `IConfiguration` into service instead of `IConfigurationRoot` or even better consider to bind/register relevant config parts to some class and inject it (see [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
)